# CDK stack stuck in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED - How to continue?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have a CDK project. I tried to deploy a stack but it had an error related to permissions. Now the stack state is UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED. I fixed the error, and I would like to continue my deployment. When I enter `cdk deploy` it fails:

`is in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state and can not be updated`

I read [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-update-rollback-failed/) that you can issue a command to ContinueUpdateRollback. Can I do this in CDK? What's the best practice for such a state? What do I do if this happens in production, I don't want to delete the stack...

Answer (score 14):

You cannot fix this in CDK -- although you can use the AWS cloudformation CLI to run `continue-update-rollback`, usually this state shouldn't be resolved programmatically because it requires a decision on your part. You have to go into the console > Cloudformation > Your Stack > Stack Actions > Continue Rollback to see what cannot be updated/rolled back.

You will be provided with a prompt as to what the exact issue is (usually a resource that cannot be updated/deleted etc). You can choose to `skip` updating this resource and the rollback will continue and succeed.

To see what went wrong with the deployment, or what tried to change that you weren't expecting, run

```bash
cdk deploy --no-execute --change-set-name debug-changeset
```

This command will not actually deploy. It will just generate a change set (called `debug-changeset`) that you can view from Cloudformation console of the stack in question. This file will show you what `cdk deploy` wanted to change and can help you debug why your update failed (I debug it this way because I find the deployment events log errors are usually not detailed enough to help you figure out the exact problem)

[image: Cloudformation console - Stack View]
[image: Cloudformation console - Continue Rollback Pop-up]

Comment: This is a good answer. We should think what we would have done if there was no CDK. Follow exactly the same steps. And keep a note of what needs to be cleaned up later.

Comment: Unfortunately this can still fail with _"Nested stack resources can only be skipped when their embedded stack statuses are one of [DELETE_COMPLETE, DELETE_IN_PROGRESS, DELETE_FAILED]"_ ...my nested stack is apparently in `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS` state, not sure if I can do anything to recover except delete the stack and start over.

Comment: Also it seems like `cdk deploy --no-execute` is not possible while the stack is in  `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED` state (gives "Error [ValidationError]")